# How to use gem rails-settings-cached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, application-settings

I have some questions and problems with the use of rails-settings-cached (https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached/blob/master/README.md)

1. I have Rails v.4.2.1. What gem I need to use? "rails-settings-cached", "0.4.1" for Rails 4.1.x or gem "rails-settings-cached", "0.3.1" for Rails 4+ ??
2. Generate settings:

   `$ rails g settings SettingsCompany`

this create model settings_company.rb and if I want to create an admin interface to editing the Settings I need create Settings controller by hand?

2.1 Name of Settings controller is matter? Can I call it the way I want?

3. Ok, I create Settings controller:

   `rails g controller Settings`

and

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # to get all items for render list
    @settings = Setting.all
  end

  def edit
    @setting = Setting.unscoped.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

this code create error:

> NameError in SettingsController#index uninitialized constant
>
> SettingsController::Setting

on string

```
@settings = Setting.unscoped
```

4. And what is "unscoped"?
5. I am a bit do not understand how to create some settings.

After this

```
`Setting.admin_password = 'supersecret'`
```

record in DB table SettingsCompany are automatically created:

```
var = admin_password 
value = supersecret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created the settings and called it `SettingsCompany` then you need to use that instead of `Setting` in the documentation e.g. instead of `Setting.all` do `SettingsCompany.all`. So to create settings do:

`SettingsCompany.admin_password = 'supersecret'`

Check out the rails guides to lean about unscoped: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields